# Version jungle MySQL.Data.xxxx.xxxx:

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm lost: I'm trying to get MySQL working in a small Console program of mine;
I have a MySQL server running on localhost which I can access via MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. No problem there.
My program gives me the following exceptions during runtime:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MethodAccessException' in MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.MethodAccessException' in MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in EntityFramework.dll
```

What am I doing wrong here? Could anyone shine some light in this version jungle?

These are the various versions of the references I included, taken from the Properties screen:

```
EntityFramework.dll version 6.0.0.0
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll version 6.0.0.0
MySQL.Data version 8.0.17.0
MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6 version 6.10.9.0
MySQL.Data.EntityFramework version 8.0.17.0
```

I'm on .NET framework 4.7.2 on Windows 10 Pro, latest updates.

My app.config looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <!-- You must un-comment the following element if you do not specify
  the connection string in program.cs -->
  <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LicenseContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=licenses;Uid=root;Pwd=-----" />
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,MySql.Data.Entity.EF6,Version=6.10.9.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.17.0" newVersion="8.0.17.0" />        
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is the start of the program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=licenses;Uid=root;Pwd=------"))
   // using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
    {
        using (LicenseContext contextDB = new LicenseContext(conn, true))
        {
            contextDB.Database.CreateIfNotExists(); // <===== here
        }
        conn.Open();
        MySqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
```

And here is the packages.config, as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.10.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

The first 4 exceptions start to appear at the "CreateIfNotExists();" line.
btw: this "Core" looks suspicious, when using .NET FW  4.72, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` and `MySQL.Data.Entities` are not official Oracle packages, and are very old. Uninstall them both and make sure they're not referenced in `app.config`.

Secondly, `MySql.Data.Entity` 6.10.9 isn't compatible with `MySql.Data` 8.0.17. Oracle [renamed the package](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,661134) to [`MySql.Data.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) for v8.x. I would recommend updating everything to the 8.x versions; you need to uninstall `MySql.Data.Entity` and install `MySql.Data.EntityFramework`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're an ace. Hm.... I can only press the up-arrow once...t

Comment: @Erik if this helped, please accept it as the answer; thanks!